# how to install other version neo4j?

Tags: windows-10, download, chocolatey

OS: Windows 10

their sites seems to give only latest version, install file

after searching a-lot, i found, chocolatey might have older version

and
i tried installing from [Chocolatey](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/neo4j-community) , keeps giving error.

> [Warning] Failed to install "neo4j-community",
> Errors: ["ERROR: The remote file either doesn't exist, is
> unauthorized, or is forbidden for url
> 'http://neo4j.com/artifact.php?name=neo4j-community-windows.zip'.
>
> Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.  See the log for
> details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).", "Failures",
> " - neo4j-community (exited 404) - Error while running
> 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\neo4j-community\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1'.

contradict to first error: The remote file actually exist, can be downloaded from browser,..  [No firewall blocking]

haven't found a solution to second error.

Is there any other way to install old neo4j

Comment: why do you keep on changing the question to something completely new?! A new question should be asked separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The download links they have on their site include the version in the link (For example, this is the link for the Windows Executable of Neo4j Community Edition 5.9.0: *go.neo4j.com/download-thanks.html?edition=community&release=**5.9.0**&flavour=winzip*).

You can simply change the URL to any release version that they had, and it will download the specific version. So for ***3.3.9*** (of Neo4j Community Edition) use **https://neo4j.com/download-thanks/?edition=community&release=3.3.9&flavour=winzip**

Once downloaded you can run/install it using the included executables and .bat scripts, see https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/windows/

Comment: @new I rolled back your "updated" question. Your old question was answered here very well. If you have a new question (which is what your "edit" was, it completely changed what you were asking) then press [**Ask Question**](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) and post a new question (if you want you can mention in the new question that it follows this one and why this thing didn't help you accomplish that goal)

Comment: oh, OK. :-].. will do that, Thanks ;;

Comment: @new Any BTW, if I answered your question here (where I think I did) you should consider accepting my answered by ticking the checkmark to the left of the answer

Comment: yes, your answer did help, Thanks For That, but i found, out i was trying wrong thing, now, i need to use latest version of neo4j. with some tweaks, thats why i had changed question, thats all..

Answer (score 0):

You can use Docker, which goes as far back as [Neo4j 3.1.9](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/neo4j/3.1.9/images/sha256-89de6a594a03dd4d7c74607695e570f2a82e032c590502e1de211cd612e1c3b6)

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try link of this form: http://dist.neo4j.org/neo4j-community-3.15.0-windows.zip

*https://neo4j.com/download-thanks/?edition=community&release=3.3.9&flavour=winzip is not working for me*

Similar SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25994850/neo4j-could-not-download-zip-version).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1224685)

Comment: I have no idea where this link has appeared, I haven't seen neo4j docs mention anything like that, and I've included a reference to a different SO question where I've got this link.